# Downgrade de package em laravel

Tags: laravel, composer, laravel-4

Estou enfrentando um problema para rodar o `composer install` devido a um pacote que esta incompatível com a versão do laravel que uso no momento;

A versão que tenho é 4.1 com php 5.6, porém quando executo o `install` recebo a mensagem;

> illuminate/support v5.5.2 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.

Infelizmente alguém atualizou o pacote e agora não consigo mais instala-lo no ambiente correto. Como posso fazer o `downgrade` para que os pacotes sejam compatíveis com a versão atual do laravel? (4.1)

Comment: Você não tem um backup do projeto antes de terem feito o upgrade?

Comment: infelizmente não @DarleiFernandoZillmer, a pessoa que fez isso fez direto no servidor de produção e ninguem sabe o que foi feito, tanto é que não registrado nada no git.

Comment: Bom mas se tem no git da pra comparar a ultima versão que tem lá com a atual já atualizada. Em todo caso, vc citou 4.1 ao final da questão e 5.1 no inicio, só pra esclarecer, qual a versão do php e laravel atuais e anteriores a atualização?

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer falha minha, ja corrigi!

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria assim:

- Remova o pacote com o comando `composer remove illuminate/support`
- Limpe o cache com o comando `composer clear` ou `composer clear-cache`. Isso é importante porque, na hora de instalar de novo, geralmente o Composer tenta pegar a versão que está no cache.
- Rode o comando `composer require illuminate/support 4.1.*`

Comment: `illuminate/support is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed`, o `support` é uma dependencia do laravel e não consta no package.json

Comment: nesse caso, acho que tem como fazer especificando a versão do laravel e removendo o cache.